# When app get rating / review?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have submitted an app to App Store. It has been downloaded almost 300 times. 5 in app purchase happened. But I do not get any review. I guess it depends on the users, whether they want to express their feelings or not. Is it any statistics when I can get the first review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on the app.

- Some apps promote reviewing and get more reviews.
- Some apps are designed for kids and do not get as many reviews, but sometimes get more reviews due to parents reviewing the app.
- Some apps' market demographics means that the users are unlikely to review an app.

There's no single average time frame. It is entirely up to the user whether they review an app, although you can mention/promote reviewing in the app itself if you wish to expedite the process.

Comment: … though any app that nags me more than twice to 'review now' gets the 'never' button or goes in the bin if there isn't one.